# Prerequisites for Hartshorne: Euclid and beyond?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, axioms

as the title suggests, I am looking for the prerequisites to Hartshorne's Euclid and beyond. I just found this book and I think it's wonderful, but the downside is that I only know math up to single variable calculus (along with some elementary topics such as basic euclidean geometry and number theory).

Thanks

Comment: Hartshorne is really a wonderful author. Based on my reading, I thought it would be accessible to anyone comfortable with proof classes, and not much other prerequisite would be necessary. It probably differs from person to person, but I won't let that stand in the way of my recommendation of this book :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to know any calculus to do geometry. I think you are all set to read it.

By the way, I am also reading Hartshorne!, but his other geometry book, also no calculus required there either.

Comment: It seems the only place where you need to know some algebra is when you learn about geometric constructions. What is constructible and what is not. Otherwise there is no need to know any algebra.

Comment: I never read the book, I just looked at its contents. It seems to me, at least, that the algebra part (field theory, by the way), is only used in one or two chapters and that is it. This means that you may be able to skip it on your first reading without ruining other chapters.

Comment: Can I recommend another geometry book for you?

Comment: How about, "Geometry Revisted", by Coxeter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one recommend that you read *Euclid's Elements* translate by Sir Thomas Heath and available as a Dover reprint in 3 Volumes.